# Deploying Local WordPress Site

Tags: localhost

I am building a WordPress site for the first time for a client. I deployed Apache and MySQL locally and installed WordPress by hand. All of the links from page to page are using the absolute URL locally (e.g. localhost:8080/index.php/a-page).

When I move to deploy this site, am I going to have to update every single link by hand? If so, is there a way to develop the site such that the links are relative to the base URL?

Answer (score 1):

**WordPress generate urls dynamically**, using the data from the database. **It is up to themes/plugins to use wordpress functionalities to generate urls instead of hardcoding them**.

**Wordpress has a series of functions that are supposed to be used when dealing with urls**, some of them are:

- `get_template_directory_url` (theme url)
- `plugin_dir_url` (plugin url)
- `get_stylesheet_directory_url` (stylesheet url)

For example, when you place an `<a href="">Menu Item</a>` in a theme template, the `href` attribute of the anchor **shoudn't have a hardcoded url** like `localhost:8080/link-to/the-post`, instead, **you should use `get_post_permalink()`** (if we are dealing with a post), that returns the relative url for the post.

If you have to use the url to an image that's located in `my-theme/assets/img/my-img.png`, you would compose the image `src` using `get_template_directory_url`, instead of hardcoding the url to the theme forlder:

`<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_url(); ?>/assets/img/my-img.png"/>`

**The same goes to files paths**. Hardcoded paths will fail if the site moves from server. **Wordpress provides functions like**

- `get_template_directory` (theme path)
- `plugin_dir_path` (plugin path)
- `get_stylesheet_directory` (stylesheet path)

---

**Some urls might end up hardcoded in the database**. It usually happens with urls in posts contents and posts metadata.

The easiest way to replace urls in the database is to use a plugin. When I have to, I use the [Better Search Replace](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/) plugin. It lets you search and replace the url in the wordpress tables.

[image: search replace]

You `search for` your old url, and `replace with` the new one. Selecting every table, and replacing GUIDs (you can read about what are GUIDs and when to replace them [here](https://deliciousbrains.com/wordpress-post-guids-sometimes-update/))